# Discord.js get an array of all messages in a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am coding a Discord bot in which I want to do the command `!quote` and it will pull a random message of of out of a specific channel with id `quotesID` (that may or may not be a different channel that `!quote` was sent in). I keep looking through the documentation for [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/general/welcome) but I can't find a way to get a [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) by its ID and then use a TextChannels `.messages` function and thus get the [MessageManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager) and then a collection of the messages.

I know I can get the guild using `msg.guild` (where `msg` is the trigger with `!quote`) or get the tex

I am new to JavaScript and Discord.js so any info helps. (I am using Discord.js version 12.2.0)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to get a specific channel with an id, you need to do:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("Your channel ID");
```

Then, to collect messages in this channel (limit is set to 100 messages max, so you can't collect more than 100 messages in this channel except if you do your own messages storing system).

```js
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
  console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`);
  //Iterate through the messages here with the variable "messages".
  messages.forEach(message => console.log(message.content))
})
```

Comment: as of now I can't iterate through messages with a `for...of` loop, it only works if I used a `forEach` function like this example

Comment: can we do something like fetch the messages between 100-200 if it's only number limit or is it like you can only fetch first 100 messages

Comment: You can only fetch the first 100 messages with this api endpoint.

Comment: I was trying out the code you have here but it's only collecting bot messages, everything else is just replies with content of ''. any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: I dont think we can pull off more than 100 messages..

Comment: @Dorian349 You can fetch all by adding a parent loop and using `before`, which is the id from the last message. So then you can get 100 messages at a time until you got all.

Answer (score 17):

According to your title, you want `all` messages in a channel. Not just 100 of them. Since there is a max on the number of messages you can fetch per request, we will have to use the `before` option to perform pagination to fetch all messages.

```js
async function fetchAllMessages() {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get("<my-channel-id>");
  let messages = [];

  // Create message pointer
  let message = await channel.messages
    .fetch({ limit: 1 })
    .then(messagePage => (messagePage.size === 1 ? messagePage.at(0) : null));

  while (message) {
    await channel.messages
      .fetch({ limit: 100, before: message.id })
      .then(messagePage => {
        messagePage.forEach(msg => messages.push(msg));

        // Update our message pointer to be the last message on the page of messages
        message = 0 < messagePage.size ? messagePage.at(messagePage.size - 1) : null;
      });
  }

  console.log(messages);  // Print all messages
}
```

Comment: And in case the OP wants to load messages synchronously, the message pointer shall be the first message of the channel, then: `let firstMessage = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1, after: "0" });`

Comment: We can even simplify a bit the message pointer update part thanks to the [`at` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) being able to cycle: `messagePage.at(-1)` will return the last element. And because our stop condition rely on the variable being falsy, we don't really need the size check: it will return `undefined` in case the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array you can use the method `<Collection>.array()` to get an array of the values in the Collection. It is like `[...Collection.values()]` or `Array.from(Collection.values())`.