# Discord bot to copy messages from one server to another?

Tags: discord, discord.js, webhooks

So, recently I tried using a bot called "Message Backup!" to save every message in, let's say "General" (not forwarding messages, but copying all previous messages in the channel) and than you can let the bot paste every message to the "General" channel in a different server with a webhook that shows the user's name and pfp. But the bot frequently runs into errors and has a cooldown that is way too long (for me).

My question is, how would I let the bot collect all messages in the channel and how would I let the bot use a webhook to resend all these messages (with username and pfp)? I don't really know how to start using the webhook thing.

Answer (score 0):

Discord allows you to, at most fetch 100 messages at a time from a channel. This is well documented, and you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71620968). If you wanted to retain the order of messages, you would most likely need to fetch all of the message first before beginning to post them elsewhere with a webhook.

Webhooks can be creted/used both manually and programmatically, but here you should create a webhook for the target channel manually. You can find a decent overview of webhooks on [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/webhooks.html).

Adapting the code from the previously linked answer with a few tweaks (such as a "before" id to allow you to restart the bot partway through, as you mentioned some issues with errors and cooldowns), you might end up with a couple functions like this:

```js
const channelID = '<channel id>';

// Passing in the id of the last message fetched before a crash should start the bot back where it left off
async function fetchAllMessages(beforeId) {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
    let messages = [];

    // Fetch parameters
    let fetchParams = { limit: 1 };
    if (beforeId) {
        fetchParams.before = beforeId;
    }

    // Create message pointer
    let message = await channel.messages
        .fetch(fetchParams)
        .then(messagePage => (messagePage.size === 1 ? messagePage.first() : null));

    while (message) {
        fetchParams = { limit: 100, before: message.id };
        await channel.messages
            .fetch(fetchParams)
            .then(messagePage => {
                messagePage.forEach(msg => messages.push(msg));

                // Update our message pointer to be the last message in the page of messages
                message = messagePage.size > 0 ? messagePage.last() : null;

                // Print out the ID of the last message fetched
                console.log(`Last message ID fetched: ${message ? message.id : 'No more messages'}`);
            });
    }

    return messages.reverse(); // Reverse messages, because we fetched them newest->oldest
}
```

And the following code to automate sending all of the messages using discord.js [`WebhookClient`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/WebhookClient)

```js
const webhookURL = '<webhook url>';
const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({ url: webhookURL });

async function cloneMessages(messages) {
    for (let msg of messages) { 
        const { content, author: { username, avatarURL } } = msg;
        await webhookClient.send(content, {
            username,
            avatarURL,
        });
    }
}
```