# get all of messages in discord channel using discord api

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

**hi im working on discord api
and for one section need to get all messages from channel**

> **problem discord api limit :** discord have limit to get messages return just 100 message

**for give more messages need before query and id
im 80 % pass this limitaion but code need imporove**

[**discord api doc**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages)

```js
import axios from "axios";



const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://discord.com/api/v9/",
    headers:{
        Authorization:"xxxx-xxxx--xxxx"
    }
});
let contents = [];

async function getContent (query="limit=100"):Promise<[]> {
    try {
        const content = await api.get(`/channels/111654654546541585/messages?${query}`);
        return content.data;
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw "[ERROR] - Request error from axios";
    }
    
}


function scrapData(slice:[], cbf:()=>void){
    if (slice.length == 0) {
        cbf();
        return;
    }
    slice.map(async (content:content, index) => {
        contents.push(content.content);
        if(index == slice.length - 1) {
            const newSlice = await getContent(`before=${content.id}&limit=100`);
            setTimeout(()=> scrapData(newSlice, cbf),3000);
        }
    })  
}


getContent().then( (data) => {
    scrapData(data, ()=> {console.log(contents)})
})
```

Comment: please clarify what you want to achieve, by looking at your question, I couldn't understand the main problem

Comment: @sina.ce main problem is in my code and loop for get all message my code is work but  need imporove in looping

Comment: could you please elaborate on what kind of improvement you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js get an array of all messages in a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322284/discord-js-get-an-array-of-all-messages-in-a-channel)

Comment: @sina.ce im using scrapData function and use cbf:callbackfunction im wana change this and looking for promis function and while loop if Possible because im want use .then 
im try async function but function in first slice done if i use promise i can resolve without any cbf:callback function